# Square API: Object version does not match latest database version

Tags: square

I'm trying to use the following Square [API endpoint](https://developer.squareup.com/reference/square/catalog/batch-upsert-catalog-objects) to update an item, but I'm getting some errors. Here is the item that I'm trying to update.

```
{
  "type": "ITEM",
  "id": "7HXK6NVBDKSOK64CCAYZJ2KW",
  "updated_at": "2020-08-08T21:43:41.849Z",
  "version": 1596923021849,
  "is_deleted": false,
  "present_at_all_locations": false,
  "present_at_location_ids": [
    "1JZ5JTPBW0EXY"
  ],
  "item_data": {
    "name": "Hummus Plate",
    "description": "Olives, feta, tomatoes, tzatziki and warm pita.",
    "visibility": "PRIVATE",
    "category_id": "ARB5LTTDUSER6T66ZWYO65FL",
    "variations": [
      {
        "type": "ITEM_VARIATION",
        "id": "HBIHPLROOJUUNUSW3BZUDQ5J",
        "updated_at": "2020-08-08T21:40:14.581Z",
        "version": 1596922814581,
        "is_deleted": false,
        "present_at_all_locations": false,
        "present_at_location_ids": [
          "1JZ5JTPBW0EXY"
        ],
        "item_variation_data": {
          "item_id": "7HXK6NVBDKSOK64CCAYZJ2KW",
          "name": "Regular",
          "ordinal": 0,
          "pricing_type": "FIXED_PRICING",
          "price_money": {
            "amount": 1000,
            "currency": "USD"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "product_type": "REGULAR",
    "skip_modifier_screen": true,
    "ecom_available": false,
    "ecom_visibility": "UNINDEXED"
  }
}
```

Here the body content.

```json
{
  "batches": [{
    "objects": [{
      "type": "ITEM_VARIATION",
      "id": "T6KKCATDIU2VV4BDBMVGML4W",
      "item_variation_data": {
        "item_id": "FNWWGFTBQWFAYK6JGBD3LDLD",
        "pricing_type": "FIXED_PRICING",
        "price_money": {
          "amount": 150,
          "currency": "USD"
        }
      }
    }]
  }],
  "idempotency_key": "61994762-3a6s-4b75-sf81-fdfaf"
}
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
**{
    "errors": [
        {
            "category": "INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR",
            "code": "VERSION_MISMATCH",
            "detail": "Object version does not match latest database version.",
            "field": "version"
        }
    ]
}**
```

[image]

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I appreciate any help I can get. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When updating a catalog object in Square, you need to provide the latest version number in the request.

```
{
  "batches": [{
    "objects": [{
      "type": "ITEM_VARIATION",
      "id": "T6KKCATDIU2VV4BDBMVGML4W",
      "version": "12345",
      "item_variation_data": {
        "item_id": "FNWWGFTBQWFAYK6JGBD3LDLD",
        "pricing_type": "FIXED_PRICING",
        "price_money": {
          "amount": 150,
          "currency": "USD"
        }
      }
    }]
  }],
  "idempotency_key": "61994762-3a6s-4b75-sf81-fdfaf"
}
```